# Correct scope for Gmail App in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail, gmail-api

When I run my code for Step 3 of the Quickstart process, I am always left with the 'Error: invalid scope' message. I have tried several different variations of the website they give and cannot figure out how to get to the next and final step.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-python

I made a few changes in order to get to the point I am already at. I changed:

```py
# Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)
```

to

```py
# Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  import argparse
from oauth2client import tools
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = argparser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, Storage, flags)
```

And the part I am stuck at is...

```py
# Check https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
```

Therefore, as of now my code is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import sys

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import run

# From samples/analytics/sample_utils.py in the google-api-python-client source

def process_flags(argv):
  """Uses the command-line flags to set the logging level.

  Args:
    argv: List of command line arguments passed to the python script.
  """

  # Let the gflags module process the command-line arguments.
  try:
    argv = FLAGS(argv)
  except gflags.FlagsError, e:
    print '%s\nUsage: %s ARGS\n%s' % (e, argv[0], FLAGS)
    sys.exit(1)

  # Set the logging according to the command-line flag.
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(getattr(logging, FLAGS.logging_level))

# Path to the client_secret.json file downloaded from the Developer Console
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

# Check https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/o/oauth2/gmail'

# Location of the credentials storage file
STORAGE = Storage('gmail.storage')

# Start the OAuth flow to retrieve credentials
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http()

# Try to retrieve credentials from storage or run the flow to generate them
credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  import argparse
from oauth2client import tools
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = argparser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, Storage, flags)

# Authorize the httplib2.Http object with our credentials
http = credentials.authorize(http)

# Build the Gmail service from discovery
gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

# Retrieve a page of threads
threads = gmail_service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute()

# Print ID for each thread
if threads['threads']:
  for thread in threads['threads']:
    print 'Thread ID: %s' % (thread['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the following scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/o/oauth2/gmail
```

which is not a [valid scope](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes).

Comment: Then what would be an example of a valid scope? I am a chemical engineer, therefore this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: See the link in the answer for valid scopes.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all of those as well. Then I come to this page:   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.compose&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=675247319315-v0r0sbsc7v2v6tjvdao8pn3eb07k6po0.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline                 which does not make sense given I do have a project that I have set up. Also, within my project it gives me "Redirect URIs"

Answer (score 0):

The way the question is posed above, see @alfasin's answer.

However, from your comment on @alfasin's answer regarding redirect URIs and the fact that you are using the Gmail-API quickstart code, your problem may be the following:

When you set up a new project in the Google Developers Console, the default redirect URI set up for OAuth is `https://www.example.com`. If you never changed that, you will need to change it in the developers console and download a new credentials JSON file. Make sure you change your application to use the new file.

(You will need to set the redirect URI to whatever URI your application is trying to redirect to, which would be visible on the error page if this is indeed what's happening to you, probably something like `http://localhost:8090/` in this case.)

Comment: I appreciate your help, @leekaiinthesky , as I was on a tight schedule with this code, i had to abandon it before you answered and go a different route. Much thanks though!